# java.io.FileNotFoundException: mounted/saved_images/Image-6999.jpg (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I create take a screenshot in Android through a button click, but image can't be saved. I have an error message in  "No such file or directory". What can I do?

My code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout L1;
    ImageView image;
    Bitmap bm;
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
    View v1;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytearrayoutputstream;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        L1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        but.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                    image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                    Log.e("top-->", String.valueOf(bitmapDrawable));



                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,60,bytearrayoutputstream);

                    //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                    File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images");
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                    File file = new File (myDir, fname);

                    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                    try
                    {

                        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

        final ScrollView scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        scrollview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                if (scrollview != null) {
                    if (scrollview.getChildAt(0).getBottom() <= (scrollview.getHeight() + scrollview.getScrollY())) {
                           View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                            Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                            image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                            Log.e("top-->", String.valueOf(bitmapDrawable));


                            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,60,bytearrayoutputstream);

                            //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images");
                            myDir.mkdirs();
                            Random generator = new Random();
                            int n = 10000;
                            n = generator.nextInt(n);
                            String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                            File file = new File (myDir, fname);

                            if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                            try
                            {

                                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                    } else {

                        View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
                        image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                        Log.e("bottom-->", String.valueOf(bitmapDrawable));

                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,60,bytearrayoutputstream);

                       // String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images");
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int n = 10000;
                        n = generator.nextInt(n);
                        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                        File file = new File (myDir, fname);

                        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                        try
                        {

                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Image can't be saved in sdcard. What mistake did I make? I can't understand what is the problem or how to save an image on sdcard?

Comment: post your code here ,manifest also

Comment: k.just a min.i post.

Comment: That is not the sdcard where you try to save your image. I think you cannot even create your directory but your cide does not tell you. ` myDir.mkdirs();`. Only call mkdirs() if the directory does not exist. And check the return value as it might fail to create the directory in which case it returns false. If so then display a toast to the user saying so. And return. Do not continue with your code as it makes little sense trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"images saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. You are also toasting success if there was a catch. Better move it to the try block.

Comment: `"No such file or directory". `. That is not the complete message. Please tell the exact full path.

Comment: then how to solve this issue.and save image in sdcard?

Comment: Did you tell exact full path? Dont think so. Why not? Sdcard? Your code has nothing to do with an sdcard. But will fail for other paths too.

Comment: then how to adapt the code in make directories?teach me

Answer (score 0):

I use this method to capture screen. First, add proper permission to save file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And this is the code (running in an Activity):

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
Date now = new Date();
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

try {
    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

    // create bitmap screen capture
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    openScreenshot(imageFile);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
```

And this is how you can open the recently generated image:

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Before write the file you have to check the  permissions  for marshmallow

```
   public static final int REQUEST_STORAGE = 101;
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE);
    } else {
     writeFile()
    }
    }

     /*check permissions  for marshmallow*/
    @SuppressWarnings("BooleanMethodIsAlwaysInverted")
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

     /*get Permissions Result*/
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "PERMISSION_GRANTED");
                    writeFile();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }


    public void writeFile()
    {
                View v1 = L1.getRootView();
                v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView02);
                image.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

                Log.e("top-->", String.valueOf(bitmapDrawable));



                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,60,bytearrayoutputstream);

                //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images");
                myDir.mkdirs();
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 10000;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                File file = new File (myDir, fname);

                if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                try
                {

                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

Comment: You are using 
  final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
 instead  of that use ,
  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

Comment: You are also using mkdirs() wrong. Moreover you should not create the file first. As new FileOutputStream() will create the file.

Comment: i changes the final string to string.but still i have error message in  " permission denied"

Comment: Before write the file you have to check the permissions for marshmallow , check updated code

Answer (score 0):

```
final String root = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
File myDir=new File(root + "/saved_images/" );
```

State is no storage. Change to:

```
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images" );
```

And adapt your code for mkdirs as explained in comment.

```
if (!myDir.exists())
  {
   if (!myDir.mkdirs())
       {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry could not create directory:\n" + myDir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
        }
    }
```

You complain that the file is not created but it starts with the directory.

You never answered my question about Androud version. But for 6.0 and above you should ask the user also for runtime permission. Add that code.

Or, as a quick solution, go to the Android settings of your app and switch the Storage toggle button to ON.